# Where should I place shared folders on an OS X Server?

Tags: macos, server.app, file-sharing

What is the appropriate/reccomended location in the drive hierarchy to place the folders shared by the users accessing the server (as fileserver) ?

Is it in `/Groups` `/Users/Shared` or `~/Documents/` ?

Or should I create a separate folder in `/Users` for each group ?

Is there a document/webpage that supplies instructions about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the shared folders for a group should go in **`/Groups/groupname/`**.
`/Users/Shared/` is more designed for local users to share, though there's nothing stopping you from using this too other than it is non-standard.

Comment: thank you. By the way I found the documentation here: http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/

Answer (score 1):

I add to the correct answer from [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside) that documentation from Apple can be found here http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/

I have to say the documentation is good but not excellent so here is a little "recipe" for the most common setup.

A common practice is to create `users`, to create `groups`, to assign `users` to `groups`. (one `user` can belong to none, one, many `groups` of course) and finally to give `groups` access to shared folders.

When a `group` is created from the Server application check the option  *Create a shared folder for this group*. As you click **Ok** to confirm the group creation the folder is created as well into `/Groups`

**Don't** create yourself the folders inside `/Groups` as this (may) mess things up (this happened to me).

You finally go to the **Sharing** pane and add the folders inside `/Groups` to the list of shared folders.
Each shared folder will be automatically set to be read-writeable by its group.

Finally you turn file sharing on.